# Simulating Multiple Feedback Low Pass filter using LTSPICE

Tags: frequency, ltspice, performance

I am trying to simulate the follwoing circuit in LTSpice IV. What I am looking for is overall performance in frequency domain.

[image]

I downloaded and readed a lot of LTSpice guides, but none of them were speaking about how to do for this kind of circuit. If you know how-to, I would really appriciate yuor help! Maybe it is stupid but I do not know what voltage source (AC, DC, sine or ...) I should use and I do not know which simulation type will be what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~prasads/LTSpice%20Sweep%20Tutorial.pdf) has a good overview of sweeps in LTSpice.

To summarize: Give your voltage source the value `AC 1` (where you currently have 1V for a DC source), and the sweep will take care of setting the frequency.

Add a `.ac` directive, either by using the `S` shortcut key and typing the Spice directive (The format is `.ac [oct|dec|lin] [step size] [start frequency] [stop frequency]`, where dec/oct/lin refer to a decade, octave, or linear sweep rate) or through the *Simulate->Edit Simulation Command* menu.

That tutorial also talks about sweeping parameter values to simultaneously plot the response with various capacitor and resistor values with the `.param` and `.step` directive.  These two tools together are very useful when designing a filter.